# Can you change your hair in Animal Crossing Gamecube?

Tags: animal-crossing

Can you change your hair in Animal Crossing Gamecube? I don't know!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change your character's hair in the GameCube version, because Shampoodle (and Harriet, the poodle) weren't introduced until Wild World.

You can make a pattern that looks like hair though at the Able Sisters though, but you will still have the horns if you're a boy, and the hat if you're a girl in-game.